# Magento2 redirect to Product Details Page on add to cart

Tags: magento2, redirect

I have disabled the Ajax cart.
When clicking on `addtocart`, it is redirected to a product page, correct I expect this to be like this.

My problem is, All products have custom options. But the Home page and category page has don't show custom options.
so clicking in `addtocart` though it redirects to the product page correctly, it shows warning info:

like - `Please specify product's required option(s).`

I want to suppress this when clicking on add to cart on the category page or homepage.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot add a product option on the catalog, the home page, and other pages. You need to go to the product detail page, choose the options, and click add to cart button.

You can imagine, if adding a product option from the catalog page, you need to do more work. I have an idea for you. For the product option, when the customer clicks Add to Cart button, we will show a popup with all info, now, the customer can choose options and add the product to the cart.

We can use the Product Quick View logic for this part. There are some Product Quick View modules.

Comment: Yes the Quick View feature is already there, but it was conflicting with other extension like advanced layered navigation.
so I am looking for a simple fix, that is how to just suppress the warning info as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: My idea is for fresh version. In your case, you should check the conflicts.